# How to scroll UICollectionView to the bottom programatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView`. I want to scroll to the bottom when the view appears. How to do this?

Can someone help me out on this?.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the below code to scroll a `UICollectionView` programmatically to the bottom

```
NSInteger section = [self numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:collectionView] - 1;
NSInteger item = [self collectionView:collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section] - 1;
NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:section];
[collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSIndexPath *lastItem = /*Indexpath of last item*/;
[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:lastItem atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

set the `contentoffset.y` of your collection view object.

Answer (score 0):

you this code to scoll down.

```
NSArray *visibleItems = [self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems];
  NSIndexPath *currentItem = [visibleItems objectAtIndex:0];
  NSIndexPath *nextItem = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:currentItem.item + 1 inSection:currentItem.section];
  [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:nextItem atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```